# React Custom Fetch Hook, force Refetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to generate a CustomHook that receives a function in charge of performing the query.
The CustomHook should perform the query and return it.

**ISSUE:**
When I change the parameter, it is not reflected in the component on the first click.
Try putting the object with the parameters in the useEffect and it loops forever

**Expected:**
Change a parameter from the front and automatically through useEffect or by executing a function, make the query again with the new parameter stored in a hook.

(The parameter must be an array, it is a function that I want to reuse)

**Actual**
https://codesandbox.io/s/usefetchwithrefetch-iw4r33?file=/src/App.js:739-745

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function App() {
  const url = "https://api.agify.io/";

  const fetcher = (urlToFetch) => {
    return fetch(urlToFetch);
  };

  const getYearByName = async (name) => {
    const response = await fetcher(url + `?name=${name}`, {
      method: "GET"
    });
    return await response.json();
  };

  const [name, setName] = useState("Nahuel");

  const { data, isLoading, getData } = useFetch([name], getYearByName);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {
        setName("Camila") 
        getData()}}>
          Change name
      </button>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div> cargando </div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>{data.name}</h1>
          <h2>{data.age}</h2>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (obj, functionTest) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await functionTest(...obj);
    setData(response);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setError(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    getData
  };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is good.The infinite loop happened because you create a new value `[name]` on each call! If you would love to stay using the array then try to destruct:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (obj, functionTest) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await functionTest(...obj);
    setData(response);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setError(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [...obj]); //<--- destruct the param to prevent infinite loop

  return {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    getData
  };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/usefetchwithrefetch-forked-0dcm0g

Comment: I was a long time and did not see it, thank you very much!